How to achieve smooth paint strokes like Adobe Illustrator in Javascript?
I'm looking for techniques or algorithms to make my webapp's strokes smooth like in those drawing apps.
Currently I have achieved calligraphy style brush but there are still jagged edges.
My Stroke script:
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let undoStack = [];
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrawing);

function startDrawing(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}

function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.lineJoin = "round";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  const dist = Math.sqrt((lastX - e.offsetX) ** 2 + (lastY - e.offsetY) ** 2);
  const maxLineWidth = 11;
  const minLineWidth = 4;
  const maxDistance = 75;
  let lineWidth =
    maxLineWidth - (dist / maxDistance) * (maxLineWidth - minLineWidth);
  lineWidth = Math.max(Math.min(lineWidth, maxLineWidth), minLineWidth);
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  ctx.stroke();
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}

function stopDrawing() {
  isDrawing = false;
  undoStack.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
}

My strokes:


Well, yeah, you're drawing lines. If you want smooth curves, draw curves (e.g. draw a cardinal spline, sometimes also called a catmull rom spline, through your points instead. Which Canvas2D has no functions for, but you can trivially convert them to equivalent Bezier curves, which Canvas2d does have functions for)

Having said that, as this is a plain web page question: it would be a good idea to turn your [mcve] into a runnable snippet. Hit [edit] and then click the little document with <> in it, in the button bar. That way folks can click the "copy snippet to answer" link that will appear in your post, fix your code, and then be able to give you an answer with an immediately runnable example of how things should work (or, work better).
